# MongoDB: Keep result of first match after second match failed in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, from a document, I have to push only the array of objects which matches the object property. Using aggregation I could able to achieve this.

But I have problem with match.

```js
Users
    .aggregate()
    .match({_id: userId})
    .unwind('tags')
    .match({"tags.name": "verified"})
    .group({
            "_id": {"id": "$_id", "type": "$type"},
            "tags": {$push: "$tags"}
        })
```

This works fine when the user has "verified" tag. But when the user don't have that result is just `[]` (empty array).

I know this the known behaviour, but how can I get matched user(since first match will return if valid user) with `tags` alone as empty array.

**Sample Collection:**

```js
{
  _id: 123,
  type: "normal",
  tags: [{name: "verified", "tagId": 1}, {name: "good", "tagId": 2}]
}

{
  _id: 122,
  type: "normal",
  tags: [{name: "good", "tagId": 2}]
}
```

So when I apply the above aggregation for userId = 123, the result is,

```js
{
   result: [
     {
       "_id": {
              "id": 123,
              "type": "normal"
       }
       "tags": [{name: "verified", "tagId": 1}]
     }
   ],
   "ok": 1
}
```

For the same if I apply with userId = 122, the result is `[]`

But the expected result is,

```js
   {
       result: [
         {
           "_id": {
                  "id": 122,
                  "type": "normal"
           }
           "tags": []
         }
       ],
       "ok": 1
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a sample document?

Comment: The current result will also help

Comment: @ZeMoon added sample collection and expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to test if the count of matches is `0` and the swap out the resulting array for an empty one where it was not. Replace values that do not match with `null` insead:

That's one approach, but another if possible is to just use [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to filter the array instead:

```js
Users.aggregate(
  [
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$name", "verified" ] }, "verified" ]
          },
          "then": "$$DESCEND",
          "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
  ],
  function(err,results) {

  }
);
```

In upcoming releases of MongoDB ( as of writing ), there will be a `$filter` aggregation operator as well. This is very simple, and will just leave the empty array behind as well:

```js
Users.aggregate(
  [
    { "$project": {
      "type": 1,
      "tags": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$tags",
          "as": "el",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [ "$$el.name", "verified" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  ],
  function(err,results) {

  }
);
```

But otherwise you basically count the number of matches and swap the array in [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) where matched count is `0`:

```js
Users.aggregate(
 [
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "type": "$type"
      },
      "tags": { 
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$tags.name", "verified" ] },
            "$tags",
            null
          ]
        }
      },
      "count": { 
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$tags.name", "verified" ] },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$tags" },
    { "$match": { 
      "$or": [
        { "tags.name": "verified" },
        { "count": 0 }
      ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "tags": { "$push": "$tags" },
      "count": { "$first": "$count" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
      "tags": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$count", 0 ] },
          [],
          "$tags"
        ]
      }
    }}
  ],
  function(err,results) {

  }
);
```

I'd go with the former one if you can. And then use `$filter` once production releases of MongoDB are supporting it.

Comment: First one works like charm. But the second solution didn't work. Please remove it or correct, so that I can accept the answer. And also question, first solution works fine, but in the query, you didn't mention "tags" field name, how did it match that, please explain more.

Comment: @sincerekamal The `$redact` pipeline operator ( which is linked to the documentation in the answer ) traverses the document at any level in the form used here and is therefore only concerned with the "name" field inside the array when in "descends" into it. Hence also the funny construct so the top level docuement ( which does not have a "name" field ) is not removed. And the only problem I see with the second listing ( which I hope you won't use anyway ) is that I typed "$userId" instead of "$_id". And that is fixed as well.